# on_message raising SyntaxError when called

Tags: python, function, discord, discord.py

This code normally works for me when I use it, but it stopped working. First with other async definitions, but now on_message isn't working!

```
async def on_ready():
    print("WizBot is currently online! Go check your Discord server; the bot should be active."

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith('+test'):
        await message.channel.send('WizBot is up and running!')
```

WizBot is the name of my bot.Also if it is helpful, I am using repl.it. on_ready() works though, but I get a pyflakes SyntaxError for the `d` in the def on_message(message).
[View error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEVFL.png)

```
File "main.py", line 21
    async def on_message(message):
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You miss a bracket in the line

```
print("WizBot is currently online! Go check your Discord server; the bot should be active."
```

It should be:

```
print("WizBot is currently online! Go check your Discord server; the bot should be active.")
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I must have accidentally deleted the bracket on accident.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because closing bracket is missing in

```
print("WizBot is currently online! Go check your Discord server; the bot should be active."
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed a parenthesis to close the `print`

```
print("WizBot is currently online! Go check your Discord server; the bot should be active."
```

while it should be

```
print("WizBot is currently online! Go check your Discord server; the bot should be active.")
```